# What's wrong with this query (UNION SELECT SUBSTRING)

Tags: mysql, union

I have a query:

```
select first_name from users where user_id=1 
UNION 
SELECT IF(SUBSTRING user(),1,4) = 'root',SLEEP(5),1);
```

Whenever I run it I get the following error:

```
ERROR 1064 (42000): You have an error in your SQL syntax; 
check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version 
for the right syntax to use near 'user(),1,4) = 'root',SLEEP(5),1)' at line 1
```

My purpose is to test whether the user is root.

`SUBSTRING user(),1,4)` means: starting from position 1, get four characters (so basically root) .If the database user is root then pause for 5 seconds.

But `SLEEP(5),1)` what does it mean apart from instructing to pause for the specified 5 sec?

Thanks a lot

Answer (score 1):

The right sintax is:

```
IF(SUBSTRING(user(),1,4) = 'root',SLEEP(5),1)
```

you are just missing a `(`. Maybe you can also use this:

```
IF(user() like "root%", SLEEP(5), 1).
```

[Sleep(n)](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/miscellaneous-functions.html#function_sleep) just pauses the execution of the query for n seconds. I don't find it really useful... but it's possible to do.

Comment: thanks a lot..I got a 5 sec pause so it means the user is root..But just to dig up a little bit..SLEEP(5),1 The 1 here what does it stand for? Thanks again

Comment: @user1990170 IF function accepts three parameters, a condition, the value to return in case the condition is true, the value to return otherwise. If user is root it will return the result of SLEEP(5) which can be 0 when the sleep succedes, and 1 when the sleep has been interrupted. If the user is not root, it will always return 1. Maybe it's better to use ,2) instead, so you know if the user is not root or the sleep has been interrupted.